# Mock non-existing class in PHPUnit 10

Tags: phpunit

Before PHPUnit 10 it was possible to mock non-existing class using next code:

```php
    $this->getMockBuilder('NonExistentClass')
            ->setMethods(['__invoke'])
            ->getMock();
```

In PHPUnit 10 the `setMethods()` is going to be removed: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/3769

New MockBuilder API introduced `addMethods()` method which is [using Reflection](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/29fe79fd73a66acb0033dea18927360ea535f552/src/Framework/MockObject/MockBuilder.php#L263) inside and does not allow to work with non-existing classes anymore.

Please advise how we can create mocks for non-existing class with new API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mock `\stdClass` as the base class:

```
$mock = $this->getMockBuilder(\stdClass::class)->addMethods(['__invoke'])->getMock();
```

Answer (score 0):

I finished with next solution:

- in my `tests` folder I've created an empty "physical" class:

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Helpers;

class EmptyCallableClass
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
    }
}
```

- then in my tests I can mock it like all others classes (example from Laravel):

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\MockObject;
use Tests\Helpers\EmptyCallableClass;
use Tests\TestCase;

class LravelMiddlewareTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @var MockObject
     */
    private $closureMock;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->closureMock = $this->createPartialMock(EmptyCallableClass::class, ['__invoke']);
    }
}
```